# Uncaught ReferenceError: renderRecaptcha is not defined

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to enable the reCAPTCHA setting on Gravity Forms. I've created a site and secret key and update the settings. Once I place the field onto my form I get this error.

I've look at where jQuery is place in the source code and this seems fine.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: renderRecaptcha is not defined
    at (index):238`

Unfortunately, I get this error so the field doesn't display at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and i fixed it with following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.getScript( "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js", function() {
        Recaptcha.create("<PUBLIC_KEY>", "recaptchadiv", {theme: "clean"});
    });
</script>
```